# how can i merge filter realm result and network search in repository

Tags: java, android, realm, rx-java2

I want merge realm result and network search and observe this result on UI.

below code work well in offline use but when updated data from net 
,Realm Auto Refresh Does not consider last search query just find all result.

What's better pattern to achive this perpose?

rx_search View

```
 @Override
public void search(Observable<CharSequence> searchObservable) {
    isSearching = true;
    Disposable subscribe = searchObservable
            .map(CharSequence::toString)
            .filter(searchViewQueryTextEvent ->
                    searchViewQueryTextEvent.length() > 1).distinctUntilChanged()
            .flatMap(s -> {
                    String[] s1=s.trim().split(" ");
                    String s2="";
                    for (String e:s1){
                        s2=s2+e+"*";
                    }

               return Observable.just(s2);
                })
              //switchMap to get result from repository
            .switchMap(s -> mInteractor.searchStores(s).onBackpressureLatest().toObservable())
            .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(stores -> {
                        if (mView != null) {
                            mView.setList(stores);
                        }
                    }, Throwable::printStackTrace
                    , () -> {
                    }, d -> disposable.add(d));
    disposable.add(subscribe);
```

get result from realm and update database from net :

```
@Override
public Flowable<RealmResults<Stores>> searchStores(String searchString) {
    searchNetwork(searchString); //  after update from net realm emit all result table
    try (Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()) {
         //Query work for first time and after update data  flowble 
         //emit all item and Does not consider  query
        RealmQuery<Stores> query = realm.where(Stores.class).like("name", searchString, Case.INSENSITIVE);
        return query
                .findAll()
                .asFlowable();

    }
}
  private void searchNetwork(CharSequence searchString) {
    api.searchList(searchString)
            .doOnError(Throwable::printStackTrace)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .filter(statusPojo::getStatus)
            .switchMap(data -> Observable.just(data.getData()))
            .subscribe(new DisposableObserver<List<Stores>>(){

                @Override
                public void onNext(List<Stores> stores) {
                    try (Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()) {
                        realm.executeTransaction(r -> r.insertOrUpdate(stores);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete() {
                }
            })
    ;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i  use switchMap to  set query every time realm flowble  emit changed result and its work :

```
@Override
public Flowable<RealmResults<Stores>> searchStores(String searchString) {
searchNetwork(searchString);

 try (Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()) {

    RealmQuery<Stores> query = realm.where(Stores.class).like("name", searchString, 
    Case.INSENSITIVE);
    return query
            .findAll()
            .asFlowable()
            .onBackpressureLatest()
            .flatMap(realmResultsCollectionChange -> 
                      query.findAll().asFlowable());

}
}
```